# Laravel htaccess, redirect specific URL to other folder

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I inherited a messy server with a Laravel project. I'm trying to test a new version without breaking the current one.

I was thinking of using .htaccess to redirect /test to a complete new folder with its own Laravel installation.

#### Current (default) htaccess

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

#### What I've tried

I tried adding the following rules right below the RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^test/$ /new [R=302, L]

RewriteRule ^test/? /new [R=302, L]
```

I get an **Internal Server Error** with both.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^test/?$ /new [R=302,L]` (remove space before `L`)

Comment: That's it, thank you! If you make it an answer i'll accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^test/?$ /new [R=302,L,NC]
```

You need to remove space before `L` otherwise it is a syntax error, that will cause 500 internal server error.